# google analytics Spreadsheet Add-on triggers

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-sheets, google-analytics-api

he Google analytics Spreadsheet Add-on and i've been watching some video tutorials that automate this report using a getData function, i've setup a Google Analytics Report in a Google Spreadsheet but i dont have access to the getData trigger or any trigger inside this add on. How can i have access to that file and use those triggers?

Answer (score 1):

Add-Ons do currently not support triggers ([it is, however, a feature wanted by many](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3858)).